# NodeJS Child process Python file error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: python, node.js

I'm fairly new to NodeJS so I apologize if the answer to my problem is obvious.
I'm trying to send data from a python file to a NodeJS server. The trick is that my python file has an infinite loop, because of it I get the error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

I haven't found a way to make my code work.

Here is my python file :

```
import time
number = 1
print(number)

while True:
    
   number +=1
   print(number)
```

And here is my node file :

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.get('/', compteur)

function compteur(req, res) {

    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

    const process = spawn('python', ['./hello.py']);
   
    process.stdout.on('data', data => {
        res.send(data.toString());
    });
}

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('server running on port 8080');
});
```

For info, I know the codes I use here are basics, but for my project, I have a python code that continuously sends data from a sensor, that's why I'm testing with this example. I believe the error comes from a callback function, but I haven't been able to fix it.

Once again I'm really new to NodeJS, so my apologies if I made a basic mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You python code is not causing the issue.

You are trying to respond multiple times to the same request (which you can't because that is not how HTTP works -> one request/one response).

this

```
process.stdout.on('data', data => {
    res.send(data.toString());
});
```

is being invoked every time `data` event fires. Just store the data and send the response outside of the `process.stdout.on` in the `end` event.

Something like

```
// init data-container here

process.stdout.on('data', data => {
    // append data to data-container
});

process.stdout.on('end', () => {
    return res.send...
});
```